# Using Notepad++ regex, match all spaces between specific characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to clean up some assembly code and I'd like to convert the spaces between the instruction and argument to tabs. However, I'd like to avoid inadvertently converting the spaces between the words in the comments after the semicolon.

So here is an example some lines of code:

```
label:          bcf INTCON,2                ; comment comment and more comment.
                btfss PORTA,2
```

The closest I've come is `(?<=^).+(?=;)`. This not only matches EVERYTHING between the beginning of the line and the semicolon, but it includes all semicolons except for the very last semicolon. Imagine lines of codes with comments that was commented out. It also doesn't take into consideration line without comments.

How do I do this?

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I was just in the middle of trying to make the code part look proper and you beat me to it. :)
Basically change the space between bcf INTCON,2 to two tabs and do this for all the lines of code.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I'm afraid none of these answers solve this problem. Let's look at this way: match and highlight the very first space on the line and that's it. And I mean *space* as in \0x20, not white space (tabs, etc.). There is only 1 space character between the beginning of the line and the first semicolon. I want to avoid everything after and including the first semicolon.

Comment: So those are tab characters before the instruction and after the operands, not spaces?

Comment: How about something simple like [`;.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b \b`](https://regex101.com/r/YItZA4/2)

Comment: @makdemir Do you mean matching the first space like this? `^.*?\S\K (?=\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/4MMA1T/1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
^([^:\r\n]+:)\s*([^\r\n]+?)(?:$|\s{2,})(;.*)?$
```

and a replacement of,

```
$1      $2      $3
```

might be OK to start with.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPtfwA/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2dCWBI/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/2dCWBI/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the space between bcf and INTCON,2 to 2 tabs, you might match the 2 "words" and make sure that they don't start with a `;`

```
^(?:\S+:)?\h+(?!;)\S+\K\h+(?=[^\s;])
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\S+:)?` Optionally match 1+ non whitespace chars and `:`
- `\h+(?!;)` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, then assert what is on the right is not a `;`
- `\S+\K` Match 1+ non whitespace chars, forget what was matched
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars (this match will be replaced)
- `(?=[^\s;])` Assert what is on the right is not a whitespace char or `;`

In the replacement use 2 tabs `\t\t`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XG6pgg/1)

**Edit**

If you want to find the first space between non whitespace chars, you might use

```
^.*?\S\K (?=\S)
```

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\w+:)\h+|^\h+`
- Replace with: `(?1$1\t:\t\t)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (\w+:)    # group 1, 1 or more word characters followed by colon
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
 |          # OR
^           # beginning of line
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists, then
  $1\t      #  content of group 1 and a tab
 :          # else
  \t\t      #  2 tabs
)           # end conditional replace
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]